# Angular 2 Setup Issue with cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

First of all i am new to Angular 2 and i created new project using Angular cli tool.

I have pushed my code here (rather then pasting all files here):

https://github.com/tsingh38/Angular2

When i run ng serve then serve starts successfully but browser shows just "Loading".

As per my research so far, package.json and other files are perfectly fine.
In case more info is required then i will answer.

Thanks.

Comment: any errors on the console?

Comment: press F12 and provide error information from browser

Comment: angular-cli is good but it comes at second stage. you should go through some basics of angular first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your `src/index.html` file and change this:

```
<app-root>Loading...</app-root>
```

To this:

```
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
```

Why? Because on your `src/app/app.component.ts` your selector is `my-app`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

Comment: Thanks your solution works but please make me one thing clear, how come angular is going to index.html first, i thought app.component is the first thing in angular and it will look for html defined in app.component ? index.html has priority or what ?

Comment: Yes, `index.html` is the first thing that is rendered by the browser, then after that Angular is boostraped and it starts reading your components html

Comment: thanks a lot for clearing my doubt, it makes sense now :)